# Publish rosbag image on a topic other than /camera/image_raw

Tags: ros

Is it possible to play a rosbag file containing images on a topic other than /camera/image_raw?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, you can simply [remap your arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) or [remap your topic-tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap).

- You can do it from terminal level when you play a single node:

> ```
> rosbag play mybagfile.bag /camera/image_raw:=/dataset/name
> ```

- You can do it from roslaunch file before [your rosbag play command](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline). It is useful when you run a several nodes.

remap example:

> ```
> <remap from = "/camera/image_raw" to = "/dataset/name" />
> ```

roslaunch example:

```
<launch>
<arg name = "pathToRosbag"  default = "/home/path/to/Rosbag.bag" />
<remap from = "/camera/image_raw" to = "/dataset/name" />
<node pkg  = "rosbag"
      type = "play"
      name = "player"
      args = "$(arg pathToRosbag)"/>
</launch>
```

Comment: I think it is a rather rare case to have a launch file for playing bag files. You can also easily do it on the terminal, though: `rosbag play mybagfile.bag /camera_image_raw:=/dataset/name`

Comment: Sure, it depends what do you need, however I have never play only one node - rosbag, it is coming always with others nodes.
PS: Thanks, I used your hint to upgrade the answer, regards.